# How do i iterate over all tags in main blog page in grav cms

Tags: php, twig, content-management-system, yaml, grav

I have the following defined in my `user/config/site.yaml` file.

```
title: Grav
author:
  name: Joe Bloggs
  email: 'joe@test.com'
metadata:
    description: 'Grav is an easy to use, yet powerful, open source flat-file CMS'
taxonomies: [tag,author]
```

As you can see i have the following defined as tamonomies:

```
taxonomies: [tag,author]
```

Now in my indivisual blog post i have the following defined in the header:

```
---
title: 'My Blog post one'
visible: true
summery: 'Pellentesque ornare mi nec elementum fringilla. Nam aliquam urna metus, vel convallis leo vulputate ut. Sed ac tempor turpis, ut pellentesque nisi. Nulla in dui sit amet augue iaculis euismod ac a massa. Sed sollicitudin nibh nisi, eu efficitur ligula vulputate a.'
header_image_file : css-thumb.jpg
taxonomy:
    tag: [JS, jQuery , CSS]
    author: papita
---
```

As you can see i have the following tags defined:

```
tag: [JS, jQuery , CSS]
```

**ISSUE ::-**

What i would like to do is in my main blog page in a side bar and output all the tags inside a list like so::-

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="">{{ tag name }}</a><span>{{  number of articles that are tagged with this tag name }}</span></li>
  <li><a href="">{{ tag name }}</a><span>{{  number of articles that are tagged with this tag name }}</span></li>
  <li><a href="">{{ tag name }}</a><span>{{  number of articles that are tagged with this tag name }}</span></li>
</ul>
```

Now i have tried the following 2 approaches that get me close:

```
<ul> 
    {% for post in page.collection() %}
        <li><a href={{ post.url }}> {{ post.title }} </a></li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

This ofcourse does't give me the tag names but just every blog individual blog post. I also tried the below:

```
<ul> 
    {% for tag in config.site.taxonomies %}
        <li><a href="#"> {{ tag }} </a></li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

But this too does't seem to do much good , what else can i try so i get the desired result ? how to iterate over all the tags, and show the number of articles published for each tag ?

Answer (score 2):

If you define the tags in the header of your page `.md` file you easily can loop over them with the following code snippet:

`{% for tag in page.taxonomy.tag %} <li><a href="#"> {{ tag }} </a></li> {% endfor %}`

For further information have a look at the official docs or the grav default theme `Quark`

https://learn.getgrav.org/content/taxonomy

https://github.com/getgrav/grav-theme-quark/blob/develop/templates/partials/blog/taxonomy.html.twig

In general I would recommend that you have a look at the default themes and demos on the official grav page for this kind of problem. Often you find the right examples for your need.